# Model binding select option value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use pure html since I do not like the @Html class.

How do I get the value from an option in a select input ?

The model binder gives me the text property of an option and not the value, as I would have liked :)

Do I really have to use Request.From[""] to do it ?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This will make the text attribute, not the value attribute, appear in the viewmodel

```
public ActionResult UpdateCard( UpdateCreditCardViewModel form )...
```

And if I just add another parameter with the input name, then the viewmodel is correcly populated. I don't have to do anything else it seems.

```
public ActionResult UpdateCard( UpdateCreditCardViewModel form, string Country )...
```

I guess that's the default behaviour ?

Comment: in mvc the Controller Default is [GET],
you can set it to [HTTPPOST] and then use if like

[HTTPPOST]
public action result "Your Method Name" (string PropertyName)...

Comment: Are you trying to get it in your client side code or in your controller?

Comment: The `ModelBinder` will **not** give you the text value of `select` (unless the text and the value attribute are the same). A select only posts back the value attribute of the selected option!

Comment: @StephenMuecke wrong. That's exactly what it does. As it shows in the example above.

Comment: It does not. You should do some basic study of html and http. A `select` posts back the value of the selected option, not to mention that you haven't even given an example

Comment: This has nothing to do with a basic study of an http form post, this has to do with a model binding for the framwework. Like the question says.

Comment: Your not understanding the basics of MVC. The following html `<Select name="Country"><option value="1">France</option><option value="2">Germany</option></select>` will post back `Country="2"` (not `Country="Germany"`) if the second option is selected (i.e the value of the option, not the text). If you model contains `public string Country { get; set; }` then the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind it. _That's the default behaviour_